# We haven't been able to use the fan for a fortnight

Tags: metaphors

In a [John Clarke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Clarke_%28satirist%29) and [Brian Dawe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryan_Dawe) interview, the phrase,"we haven't been able to use the fan for nearly a fortnight." What metaphoric expression was this phrase actually referring to? I've googled for ages and come up against a blank wall.

Comment: Can you post a link to the interview so we can see the phrase in context?

Comment: you have a link for that interview?

Comment: Hmmm... I'll have to look around a bit. I actually read it in a book.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-8UV2nJkh0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

He's referring to the phrase ["When the shit hits the fan"](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/407950.html). The senator mentions in the interview that the last time he made speculative comment about the issue he wasn't able to use the fan for a while. This, presumably, is because when he made the comments last time *so  much shit hit the fan* that he wasn't able to use it for a fortnight.

No one likes a shitty fan.